# cannot open file 'Rplots.pdf' using rapache

Tags: r, rapache

I am trying to generate a pie chart on my browser using rApache

my R code is this

```
library(MASS)                  
school = painters$School  
school.freq = table(school)
pie(school.freq)
```

when i run this on browser ... i am getting this error

> **rApache** has something to tell you. View source and read the
>   HTML comments at the end.
>
> Error in function (file =
>   ifelse(onefile, "Rplots.pdf", "Rplot%03d.pdf"),  :   cannot open file
>   'Rplots.pdf'

any idea why i am getting this error?

Comment: It seems you are not dumping the pdf. See ?pdf for more information.

Comment: Like Paul says, at the start of your code there should be a command `pdf(...)` (replace ... with file name etc, see `?pdf`) which tells R that all subsequent graphics go to the pdf file, and then at the end there should be `dev.off()`, which writes the file so it can be opened.

Comment: Well it is working using command line R.. but it is not displaying any graph using rapache on browser

Answer (score 3):

pie() and other plotting commands will try to write to a PDF by default. If you want to display an image in a web page using RApache, then this approach is not what you want.  You have to tell RApache what you want it to do.

Look in the *test* directory which was created when you unpacked the RApache source code. There, you will find several scripts which illustrate how to render a PNG image on the web page.  For example in sendBin.R, you will find this code:

```
setContentType("image/png")
t <- tempfile()
png(t,type="cairo")
plot(rnorm(10))
dev.off()
sendBin(readBin(t,'raw',n=file.info(t)$size))
unlink(t)
DONE
```

If you replace the line *plot(rnorm(10))* with your *pie(school.freq)*, then save this file in the right place (*e.g. /var/www/R/plot.R*), your chart should appear on the web page.

Make sure you read the RApache documentation and configure it so as R scripts can be run from locations in your web root.